# SQL How to return a certain string the 1st time you find a certain character/string

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a column with string examples of:

"Plan selected: Amount $5,000.00 Plan Not Select: Amount $4,000.00"
"Plan selected: Amount $500.00 Plan Not Select: Amount $3,000.00"

I would like to return the amounts of $5,000.00 and $500.00. I essentially need to return the "$" sign to ".00" when the string "Plan selected: Amount" is found.

Example Code: Select REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.description, 23, 9), ',', '') From Table t

However, if the amount is smaller it won't return the same where i'd like it to cut off at the ".00"

Thank you!

Comment: please tag with proper database platform. a regular expression of some sorts should work.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Does your data always have the format `"Plan selected: Amount $nn,nnn.nn Plan Not Select: Amount $n,nnn.nn"` , in which the numbers nn,nnn are the only thing which varies?

Comment: Yes, technically the only variables/changes to the string should be the amount "$n,nnn.nn". There could be amounts that are $n.nn as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data that you are giving This is how it should be done;
(I'll provide code for a fixed string first)

**This is assuming that you always get data in the format you specified**

```
Set @Start := 'Plan selected: Amount $';
Set @End := '.00 ';
Set @Str := 'Plan selected: Amount $5,000.00 Plan Not Select: Amount $4,000.00';
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(@Str, @Start, -1), @End, 1);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc2eaf21f3f5660b3be5476196609748)